# find_by_sql and pagination with kamanari

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pagination, find-by-sql

I have a model that connects to an external database and I query using the find_by_sql method like so:

External.find_by_sql("SELECT * from table")

However when I add the .page(params[:page]), the error "undefined method page for class array" appears.  Is it possible to paginate the results fetched using find_by_sql?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you cannot avoid using find_by_sql, check out last question of [kaminari wiki](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari/wiki/Kaminari-recipes).

Comment: The last item in the wiki is: Using Kaminari with InheritedResources. I don't see anything in the wiki about `find_by_sql`.

Comment: It was probably this one: https://github.com/kaminari/kaminari/wiki/Kaminari-recipes/e114c562b3b9a4896ad2d3db10e56eadf5d213dd#-how-to-paginate-an-array-i-need-page-and-per-for-array-class or the one after

Answer (score 10):

This worked for me:

```
Kaminari.paginate_array(my_array_object).page(params[:page]).per(10)
```

https://github.com/kaminari/kaminari/wiki/Kaminari-recipes#-how-do-i-paginate-an-array

Comment: This is great if you know your array will never be too large. Otherwise, you still load all the objects into memory, I believe.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the kaminari plugin it seems to only apply to ActiveRecord and ActiveRecord scopes, but find_by_sql does not work as a scope, but rather returns an Array.

I haven't found, digging through kaminari, a transparent way to 'paginate' an array.  You could try to roll it by hand, but it might be tricky.